# Gufw does not open in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, gufw

I'm using Remote Desktop Manager to access another system which uses Ubuntu 14.04 with Xfce 4.10 desktop. I recently installed Gufw. When I click it from Application Menu\Systems, it does not open.

update: When I try to open it in terminal it just says "Hangup".
update 2: I tried to open Gufw directly (without remote desktop). It was opened. So, the problem is that Gufw can't be opened through remote desktop and Xfce desktop.

Comment: try to launch it from terminal, it can give us some debug information

Comment: How can I launch it from terminal?

Comment: with `gufw` command in your terminal

Comment: It just says "Hangup".

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with both Synaptic and gufw on a Ubuntu 14.04 system on which I use the LXDE desktop (including its menu system).  It seems to have something to do with the switch to `pkexec` vs. `gksudo` - apps which require root access that launched a year ago from the menu, don't any more.

In my case I could launch gufw from the command line.  If you cannot, there may another problem.

A workaround for me was to edit the LXDE menu entry - formerly `Exec=gufw` and replace it with `Exec=gksudo gufw`.  This causes the menu entry to launch the app and prompt for your root password, as expected.

I do not know the xfce menu system but perhaps you could do a similar workaround.